# Multiple Joomla Login modules

Tags: web, authentication, joomla, module

Is it possible to have two login modules for a Joomla site?  I need both to be active and allow different access to different areas of the site.  What's the best way to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not actually asking the correct thing in joomla .

You can put as many login modules as you like on your site, but they will all use the same data in the Joomla user table to log the user in.

What you are looking for is either access control levels that allows you to control the content that each user sees,

or

you need components that maintain their own user 
lists independent of the Joomla users table.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/frontend-access-control